# Gas behaviour - compression

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, ideal-gas, reversibility, adiabatic

I have read that the *slow* compression of a gas results in an increase in its temperature. Is it essential that the gas be compressed slowly? What happens if the gas is compresses quickly?

Comment: Why don't you run a calculation using the 1st law of thermodynamics to  see what happens if you gradually change the external pressure compared to rapidly changing it to the same final value?

Answer (score 2):

It is sufficient that there is no exchange of heat with the environment - slow or fast doesn't come into it. You are doing work on the gas and that changes its internal energy. This is called [adiabatic compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_process). The expression linking volume and temperature is then

$$T V^{\gamma-1} = \rm{const}$$

Where $\gamma$ is the ratio of heat capacity at constant pressure, $c_p$ and constant volume, $c_v$. Of course when the volume is constant, no work is done externally by a gas being heated, so $c_v\lt c_p$ and $\gamma \gt 1$ always. A full derivation of the above can be found [here](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/sm1/lectures/node53.html)

You can think of it like this: if you are moving a piston into a cylinder (to compress the gas) then molecules that hit the piston with one velocity will bounce back with slightly higher velocity. So as you compress the gas, the average velocity of the molecules increases: at a molecular level, that's how temperature works.